# Freeswitch - multiple calls into conference room.

Tags: tcp, freeswitch, conference

We have 120+ clients using PJSIP calling into the same conference room in a Freeswitch server via a cellular network. Freeswitch accepts the first INVITE of a client then sends auth challenge back. Since the second INVITE packet size is > 1300 PJSIP sends the second INVITE with the proxy auth in TCP. For 60%+ of the calls the Freeswitch server is closing the TCP connection. A dump of wireshark trace would look like:

- From client: INVITE
- From server: 100 trying
- From server: 407 proxy auth required
- From client: ACK PJSIP acks the first INVITE on UDP
- From client: SYN
- From FS:     SYN,ACK
- From client: ACK
- From FS:     FIN,ACK
- From client: ACK
- From client: [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
- From client: INVITE   - with the proxy auth
- From FS:     RST,ACK
- From FS:     RST

Call fails - Freeswitch does not receive the second invite because the connection is closed. Cannot figure out why the server is closing the connection. It almost looks random.
When the calls start coming in some clients make it some don't. It's not just the first 50 or so. During the call the server cpu goes to about 60%. The call can last around 4 minutes.

The Freeswitch logs do not show TCP failure.
I have set the following:

In \FreeSwitch\conf\sip_profiles\internal.xml

```
<param name="debug" value="9"/>
<param name="sip-trace" value="on/>
```

In \FreeSwitch\conf\autoload_configs\sofia.conf.xml

```
<param name="log-level" value="9"/>
<param name="tracelevel" value="DEBUG"/>
```

About 50 of 120 clients make the call. The client will periodically keep trying to join the call if it fails until some specified end of call timer is reached.

The Server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit 8Gb   2 2.6Ghz procs

Any help in how to continue troubleshooting this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Lou

Answer (score 0):

Lou, I think this question belongs to serverfault.com, not stackoverflow.

I'd suggest you to try to connect to the FreeSWITCH server with a different SIP client, like Zoiper, and test how it works in TCP-only mode.